# Is that possible to inject an EJB from a different application/EAR?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I'm finishing an EJB Service that will be used in some other projects, so that I need to get it inject into some ManagedBeans, other EJBs and even a Servlet.

We already have some application dependency but it's been always single dependencies, so we are used to deploy in this way:

```
App1Ear
|
 libs
   |
    AppXModel.jar
    AppXEJB.jar
|
App1Model.jar
App1EJB.jar
App1Web.war 
|
```

The projetct I'm working in will be used in 4 applications, so if we follow this model we would deploy the applications as this:

```
App1Ear
|
 libs
   |
    MyNewServiceJB.jar
|

App2Ear
|
 libs
   |
    MyNewServiceJB.jar
|

App3Ear
|
 libs
   |
    MyNewServiceJB.jar
|
```

And so on...

So I started thinking if it would not be better - if possible - to deploy the new EJB application "stand alone" within an .EAR and get it remotely injected in other applications, so that we will not have a lot of intances of the same thing runing in the server - WebSphere Application Server 8.0 by the way.

My ideia is make it:

```
MyNewService.EAR
 |
  MyNewServiceEJB.jar
 |
```

I already made a research about injecting remote EJBs, but mostly of the results I found was about injecting EJBs from different applications but within the same .EAR, and the tests I tried did not work at all!

I tried to inject on a Servlet in this way

```
@EJB(lookup="java:global/MyNewServiceEAR/MyNewServiceEJB/BusinessImpl!com.bla.bla.bla.RemoteInterface")
RemoteInterface remoteService;
```

This JNDI above was got from the console during deploy time, so I bet there is nothing wrong about it.

what I get:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionConfigurationException: Failed to process xml from Deployment Descriptor
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processXML(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:746)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processInjectionMetaData(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:456)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processInjectionMetaData(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:379)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.process(ReferenceContextImpl.java:965)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionConfigurationException: The com.app.service.BusinessImpl interface specified for <ejb-ref> or <ejb-local-ref> could not be found
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.processor.EJBInjectionBinding.loadClass(EJBInjectionBinding.java:1379)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.processor.EJBInjectionBinding.getEJBInjectionType(EJBInjectionBinding.java:1161)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.processor.EJBProcessor.processXML(EJBProcessor.java:200)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processXML(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:736)
    ... 85 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.app.service.BusinessImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:240)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:701)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:680)
    at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:133)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:663)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:599)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:663)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:567)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:663)
    at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:567)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:663)
    at com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.processor.EJBInjectionBinding.loadClass(EJBInjectionBinding.java:1363)
    ... 88 more
```

Is that possible to do??? If it is, how? What am I missing?

Thx

-------------Editing with Interface and Implementation code ------

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class BusinessImpl implements RemoteInterface {

    public void doSomething(BusinessVO businessVO) throws BusinessException{
        ...business implenetation
    }
}
```

And the interface:

```
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface RemoteInterface {
        public void doSomething(BusinessVO businessVO);
}
```

Comment: The jdni name looks good. It actually find the SessionBean but cant create a remote reference to it. Because it can not find the BusinessImpl (it should not even know the class is relevant). Whats the code for BusinessImpl and the interface? I assume the MyNewService application started without problems?.

Comment: Thx for your attention, I edit the original post with interface/impl code, for now it has only one method as the service are being develped.

Comment: Have you tried the other way, which is mark the bean with `@Remote(InterfaceName.class)` ?